# How to access riot and router objects from within RiotJS tag script, when webpacked with riot-tag-loader

Tags: javascript, webpack, riot.js

When I use [riot-tag-loader](https://github.com/riot/tag-loader) to webpack my tags, neither `riot` or `route` object are defined inside the script area or inline scripts.
[image]

I have a router tag, and that works with `a href` hashes. But this way I can't change location programmaticaly.
[Without webpack](http://plnkr.co/edit/ekSUJheXV2JNo7vgUBGb?p=preview) works like a charm.
Works in the official [webpack demo](https://github.com/riot/examples/tree/gh-pages/webpack), even after stepping back from es6. My webpack config is much more complex, the hack might be there.

**I have created a minimal test case here: https://github.com/zorgoz/psilog.bughunt**

Please take a look and advise. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Set your webpack configuration to automatically load `riot-route` module whenever `route` identifier is encountered by using the `ProvidePlugin` to map the identifier to the module. *e.g.*

```
new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    ...
    riot: 'riot',
    route: ['riot-route', 'default'],
    Popper: ['popper.js', 'default']
})
```

Comment: Thank you, I will check!